# SQL SELECT multiple data in table and calculate

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I want to SELECT and calculate with multiple SELECT statements.

The SQL statements I want to run are:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) as total1
FROM trans
WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 120;

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) as total2
FROM trans
WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 121;

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) as total3
FROM trans
WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 480;
```

After the results are selected I want to sum the total (total1 + total2 + total3). Does someone know if this is possible in mysql?

My table structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE trans
    (`id` int, 
    `user_id` int(11), 
    `f_id` varchar(55), 
    `k_id` int(11), 
    `left` varchar(55), 
    `right` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO trans
    (`id`, `user_id`, `f_id` , `k_id`, `left`, `right`)
VALUES
    (1, '2', 'F/12C', '120', '0', '1250.00'),
    (2, '2', 'F/1B3', '121', '0', '225.50'),
    (3, '2', 'F/1B3', '654', '0', '26.50'),
    (4, '2', 'F/1B3', '612', '0', '12.50'),
    (5, '2', 'F/A23', '480', '1512.50', '112.00'),
    (6, '2', 'F/A23', '412', '112.50', '742.00'),
    (7, '2', 'F/1D3', '220', '0', '50.00')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT k_id, COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) as total1
FROM trans
WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id IN (120, 121, 480)
GROUP BY k_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: I am testing the statement. For so far its working, but I get the result in 2 rows. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @John . . . You should be getting the total row and one row for each `k_id` in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  ( (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) 
FROM trans WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 120) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) 
FROM trans WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 121) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(right), 0) 
FROM trans WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 480) ) as sum FROM trans LIMIT 0,1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both

```
//First One
    select (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trans.left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(trans.right), 0) as total1
    FROM trans
    WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 120)
    +
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trans.left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(trans.right), 0) as total2
    FROM trans
    WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 121)
    +
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trans.left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(trans.right), 0) as total3
    FROM trans
    WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id = 480) as sum;

//Second One    
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trans.left), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(trans.right), 0) as sum
        FROM trans
        WHERE user_id = 2 AND k_id in (120 ,121,480);
```